# How to access multidimensional object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array

Here is my code:

```
var obj ={
    "item":{
        name:"manu",
        nachname:"kostner",
        beruf:"astronaut"
    },
    "item":{
        name:"juliad",
        nachname:"sib",
        beruf:"mönch"
    }    
  };
  alert(obj.item[0].name);
```

`alert(obj.item.name);` is working, but I don't want to give every item a new name..

Comment: Then why don't just use `array` to contain those objects?

Comment: have you tried javascript  loop?

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on basic JS data types such as objects vs. arrays.

Comment: Your object structure is look wrong.There are two object with same keys "item"

Answer (score 1):

You have to use array, as keys in objects have to be unique:

```
var arr = [{
      name:"manu",
      nachname:"kostner",
      beruf:"astronaut"
    }, {
      name:"manu",
      nachname:"kostner",
      beruf:"astronaut"
    }];

alert(arr[0].name);
```